# i am not able to send email from via php using office 365 smtp on wamp

Tags: php, smtp

```
function send_mail($email,$message,$subject)
{                       
    require_once('mailer/class.phpmailer.php');
    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->IsSMTP(); 
    $mail->SMTPDebug  = 0;                     
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;                  
    $mail->SMTPSecure = "tls";                 
    $mail->Host       = "smtp.office365.com";      
    $mail->Port       = 578;             
    $mail->AddAddress($email);
    $mail->Username="slietnss@sliet.ac.in";  
    $mail->Password="************";            
    $mail->SetFrom('slietnss@sliet.ac.in','SLIET NSS');
    $mail->AddReplyTo("slietnss@sliet.ac.in","SLIET NSS");
    $mail->Subject    = $subject;
    $mail->MsgHTML($message);
    $mail->Send();
}   }`
```

Dear friends i have tried many things but am not able to send email through office smtp in php

Here is my mail function its showing few errors

`SMTP -> FROM SERVER:502 Command not implemented 
SMTP -> ERROR: STARTTLS not accepted from server: 502 Command not implemented 
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 2.0.0 Resetting 
Language string failed to load: tls`

please help.

Comment: Looks like that smtp server is from the stone ages...

Comment: i am using wamp server and PHPmailer

Comment: I was referring to the _server_, the smtp server that apparently is not able to use any form of encryption at all.

Comment: ok so what is the solution for that

Comment: Well, if that really is the case (only they can say, ask them), then you do not want to use that server. You certainly want to send your messages via an encrypted connection. So the answer would be: use another smtp server. But before that it might also be worth trying around a bit with your settings in that mailer object. 1. find out what that server supports, 2. check the mailing class' documentation how to use that. If that does not work, use a normal, good smtp server you have access to.

Comment: Okay. Thanks dear for a productive reply.

Comment: remove smtpsecure and try and make smtpdebug on.

Comment: can you please elaborate siddhesh